# Nifi Fetching Data From Oracle Issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I am having a requirement to fetch data from oracle and upload into google cloud storage.

I am using executeSql proecssor but it is failing for large table and even for table with 1million records of approx 45mb size it is taking 2hrs to pull.

The table name are getting passed using restapi to listenHttp which passes them to executeSql. I cant use QueryDatabase because the number of table are dynamic and calls to start the fetch is also dynamic using a UI and Nifi RestUi.

Please suggest any tuning parameter in ExecuteSql Processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are talking about having the capability to have smaller flow files and possibly sending them downstream while the processor is still working on the (large) result set. For QueryDatabaseTable this was added in NiFi 1.6.0 (via [NIFI-4836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4836)) and in an upcoming release (NiFi 1.8.0 via [NIFI-1251](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1251)) this capability will be available for ExecuteSQL as well.

You should be able to use [GenerateTableFetch](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/index.html) to do what you want. There you can set the Partition Size (which will end up being the number of rows per flow file) and you don't need a Maximum Value Column if you want to fetch the entire table each time a flow file comes in (which also allows you do handle multiple tables as you described). GenerateTableFetch will generate the SQL statements to fetch "pages" of data from the table, which should give you better, incremental performance on very large tables.

Comment: Hi matt thanks for the reply.
I was trying the exact same thing. But even in that case the execute sql processor is taking more than 30min to fetch 5000 records that form 1page size.

Comment: That can be slow on Oracle < 12 since there is a nested select to fetch then order by the row number. In NiFi 1.7.0 there is an option in GTF to use a column’s values to get the pages, so if you have an integer/long column with fairly well distributed values, maybe like millisecond (but not timestamp type) or ID values, you can use that column and it should be much faster

Comment: the table name are passed by the user from the UI and passed to nifi via rest. So there is no way i can get column name inside the processor. :(

Is there any other optimisation that can work.

Comment: I am using ojdbc7.jar with Oracle 11g. I tried with ojdc6 also but it made no difference

Comment: Unfortunately I think you’ll need to wait for 1.8.0 or build the standard NAR yourself with the patch in it.

Comment: by when is the nifi 1.8.0 release planned?

Comment: Hi matt just a question, Since this feature is already available in QueryDatabaseTable, Is it possible that when i write a custom NAR i use the same logic to work around here?

Comment: Hi, As usggested i went ahead and developed a custom nar but wile deploying i am constantly facing the below error : 

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: jar:file:/home/siddharth/Documents/Nifi-Latest/nifi-1.6.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-demo-nar-1.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-demo-processors-1.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor:15: Illegal provider-class name: hwx.processors.${artifactBaseName}.MyProcessor
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239).

Comment: if you are using the Maven archetype, it appears you may have left out the artifactBaseName property?

Comment: Hi Matt was able to resolve that but now stuck with : 

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/distributed/cache/client/Serializer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.client.Serializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass

Comment: This is probably best handled as a separate SO question

Comment: was able to resolve it. Now the custom processor is able to fetch data from oracle pretty fast in bunch of smaller files. Thanks for you support. :)